# Error when trying to run Polymer Starter Kit

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to run the [Polymer starter kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit#getting-started) but when I try to run 'gulp serve' (without the quotation) it opens the page on the browser, but it's not showing anything.

When I inspect the JS console, I'm getting the following errors:

http://localhost:3000/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles-classes.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-cache.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/platinum-sw/platinum-sw-register.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
my-greeting.html:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
my-list.html:27 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/page/page.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have to install the dependencies of your project:

```
npm install -g gulp bower && npm install && bower install
```

Check the "Install dependencies" section on https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server isn't running in the right directory.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the exact issue I had with the starter kit: brings up a blank page with the title only. You need to install the web components with bower. Change directory to your app root then, in terminal :

```
bower install --save Polymer/polymer#^1.0.0
```

I'd also suggests that you install Polymer with [Yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer), if you have not done so.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.html file at line 70,

```
* If you intend to serve your app from a non-root path (e.g., with URLs
* like `my.domain/my-app/` and `my.domain/my-app/view1`), edit this line
* to indicate the path from which you'll be serving, including leading
* and trailing slashes (e.g., `/my-app/`).
*/

window.Polymer = {rootPath: '/'};
```

To fix  the problem, simply point the rootPath to the correct directory your app is in, for example

```
window.Polymer = {rootPath: '/firstapp/'};
```